# What bootloader is present by default on Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno

Or where can i find information of default bootloaders present on each Arduino board. All I could look up was it could be one of these bootloaders on the atmega chip :-

.Atmega
.Atmega8
.bt
.caterina
.caterina-Arduino_Robot
.caterina-LilyPadUSB
.gemma
.lilypad
.optiboot
.stk500v2

This was the list present in the folder ~\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\bootloaders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is defined in the file "boards.txt" (`arduino-1.8.7\hardware\arduino\avr\boards.txt`).

For example the Arduino Uno is called "Arduino/Genuino Uno" and it has the bootloader: `uno.bootloader.file=optiboot/optiboot_atmega328.hex`

You can find that hex file in the folder `arduino-1.8.7\hardware\arduino\avr\bootloaders\optiboot`.

The official Arduino boards are shipped with the newest bootloaders.
Sometimes the bootloaders are improved or changed. That is mentioned in the Release Notes.
For example the latest change to a bootloader is that the Arduino Nano has now the same optiboot bootloader as the Arduino Uno.

When buying a Arduino clone board, anything is possible.

Some companies make there own Arduino-compatible boards with their own bootloaders.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Optiboot Bootloader for Arduino and Atmel AVR

https://github.com/Optiboot/optiboot/wiki

Take a look at this information.